# Blocking and Being New Home Screen Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to Swift and iOS programming and I wanted to know if there was a way to essentially block other applications or have your application be the default Home Screen? The idea is a time-saving application so maybe totally hide text messages and the browser when it is enabled.

I saw that there is kind of a way to do this in Android, but wasn't sure if there was a way to do this with iOS.

Comment: No, there is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. iOS does not allow apps to have this level of permissions.

However, you may be able to achieve similar effect by using the [Screen Time](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208982) feature in iOS 12+

Comment: Can you explain what ScreenTime has to do with it? How would you use it to “achieve similar effect”?

Comment: Screen Time has a "Downtime" feature that you can use to restrict your access to specific apps. Unfortunately, it will not help you in writing an app.

Comment: Right, I see, so this is the "block other apps" part. But you can't use ScreenTime to restrict the device to just _one_ app. It sounds to me more like the OP needs to look into Kiosk Mode. But that's only on an iPad, and the app doesn't put _itself_ into Kiosk Mode.

Comment: That's true. Huh — I didn't know Kiosk Mode was iPad-only. You learn something every day!

Comment: Well, I could be wrong about that; maybe I was just imagining that only an iPad would _need_ to be in a kiosk. This article seems to imply different: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202612